# Add object to context and get properties from the relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, code-first

I made a while ago some code that adds an object to my table with entity framework code first.

```
Context.Reactions.Attach(reaction);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

After that I used a relationship called Profile to get the name of the user that posted the reaction.

```
reaction.Profile.FirstName + " " + reaction.Profile.LastName
```

Now after a while, I get a nullreference on Profile when I try to get the name of the person.

So why can't I add an object and after that use the Profile relationship?

Edit:
I'm getting the nullreference on the Profile relation property. So reaction.Profile says that is null. It is the same instance. Entity Framework has given me an id for the reaction so the savechanges() works.
The line for getting the FirstName is the line directly after the SaveChanges so the context couldn't be disposed right?

Complete code:

```
var reaction = new Reaction()
                                {
                                    Text = reactionText,
                                    ProfileId = CurrentProfileId,
                                    PostedOn = DateTime.Now
                                };

                    //Save changes to the backend
                    context.Reactions.Add(reaction);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        Id = reaction.Id,
                        ReactionType = reactionType,
                        ReactionTypeId = reactionTypeId,
                        ReactionText = reaction.Text,
                        PostedOn = reaction.PostedOn.ToString("G"),
                        ProfileName = string.Format("{0} {1}", reaction.Profile.FirstName, reaction.Profile.LastName)
                    });
```

I even tryed with this code around it.

```
using (var context = new SeeTingsContext())
                {
                    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;


                }
```

Comment: you're getting the null reference exception on the same instance of the reaction? not a newly queried one?

Comment: I added my question above for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite get you when I read `after a while`. Does this mean you get the relation object  first, and then it suddenly becomes null?
My guess is:

- You have not set `LazyLoadingEnabled` to true for the context you're working on.
- Your context is disposed and thus you cannot use it to get the relationship. Note that you can use Lazy loading while your context still exists.

**Update**: Based on the comments, try to load the relation explicitly and see if you can get the profile:

```
if (!context.Entry(reaction).Reference(r => r.Profile).IsLoaded)
{
    context.Entry(reaction).Reference(r => r.Profile).Load();
}
```

If you cannot get profile using this way, I suppose there's something wrong with your mapping.

Comment: Yes with after a while I exactly mean that it worked for 1.5 month and suddenly it doesn't. I look Team Foundation Server and nothing has changed. I couldn't also find any difference in the context. As you can see, the code should be right. The id isn't null so the savechanges works.

Comment: //Load only the Profile relation explicitly
Context.Entry(reaction).Reference(r => r.Profile).Load();

I placed this code just after the SaveChanges().

Do you know why this must be done?

Comment: @LockTar: This is when you don't have lazy loading enabled. It explicitly loads the reference/collection relation. strange you couldn't use LazyLoading. Are you using WCF RIA Services? If so, Lazyloading is disabled and cannot get enabled easily due to serialization issues.